# How to access gmail via pop instead of imap in mail.app in iOS 7.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, mail.app, gmail, pop

In iOS 6.x, my iPad and iPhone were connected with pop to gmail accounts. When I delete a message on the iPad or iPhone, the message is NOT deleted on the gmail server. So the message is still in my Apple Mail box on my OSX Lion Mac. The Mac Mail uses IMAP, so when I delete a message on the Mac, it IS deleted from the gmail server and the iPad and iPhone do not show the deleted message on their next update.
     How do I implement this "Mac is master" with the iPad and iPhone on iOS 7.1? I have tried enabling POP on the gmail server and told it to keep mail on the server's inbox. But  deleting on the iPad POP client still deletes the message from the server and it's no longer available on my IMAP Mac.

I'm following instructions from "https://support.google.com/mail/topic/3398031?hl=en&ref_topic=3396281" in the POP section. Am I missing something? Or is it just not possible anymore?

Comment: But don't you find it annoying to have to "read" all the e-mails all over? Instead of deleting the e-mails why not just move them to a folder and then at the end of the year or so copy them off onto your computer and then delete them from the server (should it be nearing capacity)

Comment: With the iMac Mail using IMAP, when I delete a message on the iMac, it's automatically deleted on the gmail server. But most of my mail, I move to a local iMac folder and never delete so the gmail server copy does not get deleted. If I delete a message from my iPad (on POP), it still deletes it on the server and the iMac. I also tried MOVING a message to another folder on iPad; that also deletes on the server. What's next?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your devices settings. Select "mail, contacts, calendar" > add account 
Then choose "other" (NOT GMAIL!)
You will then be able to enter all the stuff manually and choose between imap and pop

Comment: Thanks, Kevin, but I did what you suggest but the iOS POP account still deletes the message from the gmail server. (from my original post:"I have tried enabling POP on the gmail server and told it to keep mail on the server's inbox. But deleting on the iPad POP client still deletes the message from the server and it's no longer available on my IMAP Mac.").   Is there a subtle POP configuration?

Comment: In the settings on your iOS device there's a setting for deleting messages on the server; set it to "never"

Comment: Setting Delete to Never still deletes the message from the server when I delete on the iOS device.

Comment: That's awkward. Are you sure it's configured as pop?

Comment: The thing that makes my iPad iOS 7.1  a POP connection is where the INCOMING MAIL SERVER is "pop.gmail.com" rather than "imap.gmail.com", right? I'm using Server Port 993. Anything else?   Tnx, Tony

Comment: No 993 is IMAP, when you set up the account you have a switch on top for POP/IMAP. iOS doesn't let you change it afterwards, you'll have to delete it and set it up again

Comment: Aha! I started over and did the POP selection and it behaves independent of my Mac on IMAP. But good news: I also found _my_ desired behavior with IMAP on iOS and iMac. Now, when I move a message from the iMac Mail inbox to anyplace, the message is deleted from the gmail server and iOS devices. Initially, messages were only deleted from the server's inbox if I deleted the messaage on the iMac.     Thanks for your help, Kevin